# How can i get name of USER that launched insert query in oracle

Tags: oracle, session, triggers, insert

so my home work is to create a trigger that launchs after an Insertion query on given table to update another table.. , and to read the name of USER who launched the INSERT query ! 
ANY suggestions on how to get the name of user ?

Answer (score 0):

For example, if you wanted to log inserts into Scott's EMP table, you could have done it like this:

(You don't really need this; I'm using it just to set date format):

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss';

Session altered.
```

Log table & trigger:

```
SQL> create table log_emp (empno number, who varchar2(30), datum date);

Table created.

SQL> create or replace trigger trg_ai_emp
  2    after insert on emp
  3    for each row
  4  begin
  5    merge into log_emp l
  6      using (select :new.empno empno
  7             from dual
  8            ) x
  9      on (x.empno = l.empno)
 10    when matched then update set
 11      l.who = user,
 12      l.datum = sysdate
 13    when not matched then insert values
 14      (:new.empno, user, sysdate);
 15  end;
 16  /

Trigger created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> insert into emp (empno, ename) values (1, 'Little');

1 row created.

SQL> select * from log_emp;

     EMPNO WHO                            DATUM
---------- ------------------------------ -------------------
         1 SCOTT                          30.11.2019 18:57:30

SQL>
```